# Text not adjusting according to screen size

Tags: html, css, frontend

I have this simple wrapper in HTML with simple content and simple CSS but the text is not adjusting according to screen size and overflowing

HTML

```
<div class="no-task-wrapper">
  <h2>Oops! Looks like there are no <span>Tasks</span></h2>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.no-task-wrapper {
    color: rgb(122, 122, 122);
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
}

.no-task-wrapper h2 {
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-family: var(--main-font);
}

.no-task-wrapper span {
    color: var(--main-color);
    font-size: inherit;
}
```

First Pic with no overflow

[image: No overflow img]

Second pic with overflow

[image: Over Flow Img]

Answer (score 1):

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px){
    /*Tablets [601px -> 1200px]*/
    //Here you can add your font size at different screen resolutions
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px){
    /*Big smartphones [426px -> 600px]*/
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 425px){
    /*Small smartphones [325px -> 425px]*/
}
```

You can just add a media query in your CSS file and write the styles inside media queries. Hope this will help you

Comment: Yeah i think this will help

Answer (score 0):

You may use media queries which is fine, but a cleaner way you can do it by using the clamp function. Like so (You will have to resize your screen to see the effect):

```css
.no-task-wrapper {
  color: rgb(122, 122, 122);
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.no-task-wrapper h2 {
  font-size: clamp(1rem, 4vw, 2rem); /*Like this */
  font-family: var(--main-font);
}

.no-task-wrapper span {
  color: var(--main-color);
  font-size: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="no-task-wrapper">
  <h2>Oops! Looks like there are no <span>Tasks</span></h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Nope the clamp function not helping

Comment: Then it seems there some other element that's causing your browser to overflow. I'm guessing it has something do do with your footer. Could you add a JSFiddle to your post?